# Magento 2 Add New Integration error

Tags: magento2, admin, api, integration

I have seen this has been posted before but but cannot find a definitive answer.

When trying to add a new integration `(System > Integrations > Add New Integration),` the New Integration page comes up but with nothing on it except Save and Back buttons. Clicking the Save button results in

```
Notice: Undefined index: all_resources in /vendor/magento/module-integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration.php on line 141
```

> Magento version is 2.2.6

I have tried flushing the cache and re-indexing. And I have the same problem on both the production site and staging site (default mode).

Much appreciated if anyone can help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that one of your modules doesn't have a title defined in the **acl.xml** file. The easiest way to fix this is to put below code in `src/vendor/magento/module-integration/Helper/Data.php` to  the foreach-loop:

```
if (!isset($resource['title'])) {
    throw new \Exception("Title not set for resource {$resource['id']}");
}
```

This will enable you to identify the node that is missing title Or You can work out which module by inspecting the element.

**Do revert the core file once you have identified the issue**

Comment: Thank you @Vishwas Bhatnagar. I found the module that was causing the probem by trial and error (delete the module, remove the module reference in config.php, flush cache, reload Add New Integration page). There was a title missing in etc/acl.xml. I was unable to use the Data.php code because the same issue prevented me from logging in to admin panel in developer mode. This is now fixed also. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any integration error on magento2.2.6. 
[image]

[image]

If you really have issue with fresh magento2.2.6 project please try to reinstall and setup properly, If you have the third party extension please check that module and try again.

I think it's not a bug if its bug everyone should be face the same. 
Try to reinstall magento with composer. Will be good for development side.